# Apache serves svg as base64 instead of svg

Tags: apache, ubuntu, svg

The identical PHP code is running on 2 servers.

*image.php*

```php
$svg = produce_svg(); //a 3rd party library that produces an svg
header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
die($svg);
```

On Windows, Apache produces the expected response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...
```

But on Ubuntu, calling the same URL produces a base64 encoded string instead:

```
data:image/svg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIEAQAAABXwbpWAAAABG...
```

I did not ask Apache on Ubuntu to convert the file to base64 and cannot use the base64 string. I need the actual svg.

How do I get Apache Ubuntu to produce the same response as Apache Windows? I've tried all manner of `AddType` and ensuring `mime.types` has `image/svg+xml   svg svgz`, etc. to no avail.

**Edit**

After researching for hours and finding only several loose mentions of Ubuntu having issues with .svg, we tried changing the image type to .png and were successful serving it from PHP/Apache on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: What URL are you using. Just the path will do.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out produce_svg() to be sure its generating SVG output?

Comment: I've confirmed using postman. The image is an svg of a QR code. Postman renders it, as does windows apache.